# Linq: OrderBy Sum of multiple fields

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, lambda, sql-order-by

I'm trying to create a linq expression whereby I can COUNT the number of event comments as well as SUM the number of Votes. Here's what I've got, but I'm not getting the appropriate results.

My example is done in VB.Net, but I can deal with examples in C# as well.

```
    Public Function GetHotEvents(ByVal skip As Integer) As List(Of Domain.Event) Implements IEventService.GetHotEvents
        ''# Our order by sequence just takes the number of votes and multiplies
        ''# it by two. Then takes the number of comments and adds it to the
        ''# vote count.  This way up-voted events will climb to the top while
        ''# down-voted events will fall to the bottom.  Comments also add to
        ''# the "hotness" of the event.
        Return _EventRepository.Read() _
            .Where(Function(e) e.EventDate >= Date.Today) _
            .OrderBy(Function(e) (((e.EventVotes.Sum(Function(s) s.Vote)) * 2) + (e.Comments.Count))) _
            .Skip(skip) _
            .Take(5) _
            .ToList()
    End Function
```

What I've done to test this is have ZERO comments on all events, and upvote ONE event. That event "should" float to the top, but it's not there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

#### edit

I've tried building the expression in LinqPad but unfortunately it threw an error (note: this error doesn't get thrown in my code)

> Overload resolution failed because no
>   accessible 'OrderBy' can be called
>   with these arguments:
>       Extension method 'Public Function OrderBy(Of TKey)(keySelector As
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of
>   System.Func(Of LINQPad.User.Events,
>   TKey))) As
>   System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable(Of
>   LINQPad.User.Events)' defined in
>   'System.Linq.Queryable': 'Comments' is
>   not a member of 'LINQPad.User.Events'.
>       Extension method 'Public Function OrderBy(Of TKey)(keySelector As
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of
>   System.Func(Of LINQPad.User.Events,
>   TKey))) As
>   System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable(Of
>   LINQPad.User.Events)' defined in
>   'System.Linq.Queryable': Data type(s)
>   of the type parameter(s) cannot be
>   inferred from these arguments.
>   Specifying the data type(s) explicitly
>   might correct this error.
>       Extension method 'Public Function OrderBy(Of TKey)(keySelector As
>   System.Func(Of LINQPad.User.Events,
>   TKey)) As
>   System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable(Of
>   LINQPad.User.Events)' defined in
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable': 'Comments'
>   is not a member of
>   'LINQPad.User.Events'.
>       Extension method 'Public Function OrderBy(Of TKey)(keySelector As
>   System.Func(Of LINQPad.User.Events,
>   TKey)) As
>   System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable(Of
>   LINQPad.User.Events)' defined in
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable': Data type(s)
>   of the type parameter(s) cannot be
>   inferred from these arguments.
>   Specifying the data type(s) explicitly
>   might correct this error.

#### edit 2

Here's the generated SQL

```
DECLARE @p0 Int = 2    

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Events] AS [t0]
ORDER BY (((
    SELECT SUM([t1].[Vote])
    FROM [dbo].[EventVotes] AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[EventID] = [t0].[ID]
    )) * @p0) + ((
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[Comments] AS [t2]
    WHERE [t2].[EventID] = [t0].[ID]
    ))
```

Comment: If this is LINQ to SQL, could you show us the generated SQL?

Comment: I tried to generate the SQL in LinqPad but it threw an error. I'm running "Express" so I don't have profiler. I've updated my answer to reflect the LinqPad error.

Comment: Did you mean OrderByDescending?

Comment: Alright - tow things.  1) I changed my DB reference in LinqPad to use my assembly instead of directly accessing the database, and the error went away, and my expression worked. 2) yes, changing `orderby` to `orderbydescending` worked. Bah

Comment: @Maxim, add as anwer, and I'll accept.  Can't believe I seem to miss the simplest things.

Comment: [BAHHHH - same topic, new problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719163/linq-orderbydescendingsumvotes-countcomments-not-working-as-needed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean `OrderByDescending`? ;)