# Linq: How to OrderBy the SUM of one table and the COUNT of another

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, lambda, sql-order-by

As per a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718113/linq-orderby-sum-of-multiple-fields), I've got the following LINQ expression.

```
Events.Where(Function(e) e.EventDate >= Date.Today) _
            .OrderByDescending(Function(e) (((e.EventVotes.Sum(Function(s) s.Vote)) * 2) + (e.Comments.Count))) _
            .Skip(0) _
            .Take(5)
```

Which converts to the following SQL

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 DateTime2 = '2011-01-17 00:00:00.0000000'
DECLARE @p1 Int = 2
DECLARE @p2 Int = 0
DECLARE @p3 Int = 5
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t3].[ID], [t3].[UserID], [t3].[RegionID], [t3].[LocationID], [t3].[Title], [t3].[Description], [t3].[EventDate], [t3].[URL], [t3].[Phone], [t3].[TicketPriceLow], [t3].[TicketPriceHigh], [t3].[DatePosted], [t3].[isHighlighted]
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (((
        SELECT SUM([t1].[Vote])
        FROM [dbo].[EventVotes] AS [t1]
        WHERE [t1].[EventID] = [t0].[ID]
        )) * @p1) + ((
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM [dbo].[Comments] AS [t2]
        WHERE [t2].[EventID] = [t0].[ID]
        )) DESC) AS [ROW_NUMBER], [t0].[ID], [t0].[UserID], [t0].[RegionID], [t0].[LocationID], [t0].[Title], [t0].[Description], [t0].[EventDate], [t0].[URL], [t0].[Phone], [t0].[TicketPriceLow], [t0].[TicketPriceHigh], [t0].[DatePosted], [t0].[isHighlighted]
    FROM [dbo].[Events] AS [t0]
    WHERE [t0].[EventDate] >= @p0
    ) AS [t3]
WHERE [t3].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN @p2 + 1 AND @p2 + @p3
ORDER BY [t3].[ROW_NUMBER]
```

My problem now is when it comes to ordering when some events don't have any votes or comments.

Here is what the EventVotes table looks like (in it's entirety)

```
| UserID | EventID | Vote |    
| 1      | 51      | 1    |   
| 1      | 52      | 1    |   
| 2      | 52      | 1    |   
| 1      | 53      | 1    |   
| 2      | 53      | -1   |   
| 3      | 53      | -1   |
```

The Comments table is completely empty, so since we're just doing a `Count` on it, we can assume that everything comes back Null.

Now when I run the query above, the result order is as follows

> 52
>   51
>   53
>   1
>   2
>   3

When it "should" be

> 52
>   51
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   53

because event number 53 has a vote count of "-1" while event numbers 1, 2, and 3 have a vote count of "0"

Can anyone help figure out how to enhance the Linq expression to account for events that haven't been voted on?

Here's a screenshot

[image]

## EDIT:

Ok, so I've simplified the query in LinqPad to this, and the result is that I only get three results.

```
Events.OrderByDescending(Function(e) (((e.EventVotes.Sum(Function(s) s.Vote)) * 2) + (e.Comments.Count)))
```

What this is telling me is that the orderby is only grabbing those three results (51, 52, 53), then it appends the rest of the results AFTER the order clause.  I need to figure out a way to include the rest of the "null" results in the Lambda expression.

Comment: I deleted my answer since I was unable to help and also in hopes that people will see 0 answers for this question and be more likely to read it and help you out.  My final suspicion is the over clause in your sql statement, but I'm not sure what it should be, sorry.

Comment: Thanks @Brian - I definitely don't know what's up here.

Comment: Just a note:  you may be better off, as I believe Stackoverflow does, caching the total sum of votes for each event in the Event table itself.  You have to be *very* careful of concurrency issues, but it would likely be a huge performance win.  Of course, only profiling can tell for sure, but I believe this solution would actually be *easier* anyways.. and then you avoid the problem you are facing now entirely.

Comment: wildly guessing, but do Events 1, 2 and 3 have a vote count of null, which is less than any valid number? Not sure off the top of my head why it wouldn't default to zero though.

Comment: Yes 1,2 and 3 have a vote count of null.

Comment: @BlueRaja, you're prolly right. I was planning on putting the total in the db, just hadn't gotten there yet.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring: If you insist on still doing it this way, try googling for "outer join entity framework" *(which is, from my understanding, what you are trying to do)*. I know there are multiple workarounds to do outer joins here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a C# solution.  I tried to translate it into VB, but my VB skills (and desire to learn it, honestly) are nil, and I gave up.  I'll try to highlight the critical points to help with the translation.

Here's the full statement:

```
context.Events.OrderByDescending(e => (((e.EventVotes.Sum(s => (int?)s.Vote) ?? 0) * 2) + e.Comments.Count))
```

What's critical is that `s.Vote` is first cast to a nullable integer so that the result of `Sum()` will be a nullable integer.  A nullable result allows you to explicitly check for null and use zero for the rest of calculation if the result was indeed null.

For VB translation purposes, `??` is a C# null-coalesce operator where (for example) `myNullableIntVar ?? 0` evaluates to the value of myNullableIntVar, or if it is null, then 0.

Here's the SQL generated by the above statement, FWIW:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[EventID], [t0].[Name]
FROM [dbo].[Events] AS [t0]
ORDER BY ((COALESCE((
    SELECT SUM([t2].[value])
    FROM (
        SELECT [t1].[Vote] AS [value], [t1].[EventID]
        FROM [dbo].[EventVotes] AS [t1]
        ) AS [t2]
    WHERE [t2].[EventID] = [t0].[EventID]
    ),@p0)) * @p1) + ((
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[Comments] AS [t3]
    WHERE [t3].[EventID] = [t0].[EventID]
    )) DESC',N'@p0 int,@p1 int',@p0=0,@p1=2
```

---

#### Edit by rockinthesixstring

I've added the VB.NET version below - This works exactly as expected.  I tried to do a `DirectCast(s.Vote, Integer?)` but it threw an error saying that `Integer` cannot be converted to `Integer?`, So I had to take this approach.

```
Events.OrderByDescending(Function(e) (((If(e.EventVotes.Sum(Function(s) s.Vote),
                                           e.EventVotes.Sum(Function(s) s.Vote),
                                           0)) * 2) + e.Comments.Count))
```

Which resulted in this SQL Query

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 0
DECLARE @p1 Int = 2
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[UserID], [t0].[RegionID], [t0].[LocationID], [t0].[Title], [t0].[Description], [t0].[EventDate], [t0].[URL], [t0].[Phone], [t0].[TicketPriceLow], [t0].[TicketPriceHigh], [t0].[DatePosted], [t0].[isHighlighted]
FROM [dbo].[Events] AS [t0]
ORDER BY ((
    (CASE 
        WHEN (CONVERT(Bit,(
            SELECT SUM([t1].[Vote])
            FROM [dbo].[EventVotes] AS [t1]
            WHERE [t1].[EventID] = [t0].[ID]
            ))) = 1 THEN (
            SELECT SUM([t2].[Vote])
            FROM [dbo].[EventVotes] AS [t2]
            WHERE [t2].[EventID] = [t0].[ID]
            )
        ELSE @p0
     END)) * @p1) + ((
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [dbo].[Comments] AS [t3]
    WHERE [t3].[EventID] = [t0].[ID]
    )) DESC
```

Comment: I'll give this a try. I did try the inline if statement, but didn't cast to nullable first. Thanks.

Comment: yup, that's exactly it. I've edited your answer to show the VB version.